# Issues with Multiple Runtime errors: updated code - still having issues

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, type-mismatch

**Thank you all for your help so far - it is very much appreciated!! But I am still having issues**

I am a very new user of VBA in excel and I'm sure the answer will be very simple.

I have gone through lots of attempts at fixing it by reading existing questions but each time I just get a different error and have not been able to fix the issue.

As such I have gone through many iterations of this code trying to fix the problems so would welcome advice on how to proceed.

Apologies also if I don't format / ask my question appropriately.

**Background**

I have two excel files:
wb1) One sheet with table of Company Names and IDs (list changes every week)
wb2) A workbook with multiple tabs which is essentially the template.

For every Company Listed in wb1 I need to copy the Company Name and ID into the appropriate cell in wb2 and save as Company Name & Date.

As above I have gone through many iterations and had help below but I am still not getting it to work.

The various errors I have been getting depending on how I amend the code is Runtime error 5, runtime error 438, a compile error and possibly some others I didn't write down.

**Current issue:**

If the macro is saved in wb1 -  the macro runs and creates the first workbook but then I get "System Error& h800401a8 (-2147221080)

If the macro is saved in personal macro workbook - "Script out of range". It appears to break at line `Set tb1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")`

I would welcome any advice on how to fix the problem and thank you in advance.

**This is my code as it stands:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub CreateStat()


    Dim CompanyName As String
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim tb1 As ListObject
    Dim i As Long


    Set wb1 = **struggling with this. I want to reference the workbook that has the 
table in it that is being used to draw through to the CompanyName and CompanyID. 
This is already open. 
The table is formatted as a table starting A1 with headers in row A**.
(errors come when this is set to ThisWorkbook)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\YYY\Documents\Statements\SRTemplate.xlsx")
    Set tb1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wb1.Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Z = tb1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count


    For i = 2 To Z + 1


    CompanyID = tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1)
    CompanyName = tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2)

    wb2.Activate

    wb2.Sheets("Reconciliation").Range("D3").Value = CompanyName
    wb2.Sheets("Reconciliation").Range("M3").Value = CompanyID

    ChDir "C:\Users\hannah.wyld\Documents\Statements\"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\YYY\Documents\Statements\" & CompanyName & " " & Format(Date, "MMM") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


    Windows(CompanyName & " " & Format(Date, "MMM") & ".xlsx").Close
    wb2.Activate
    wb2.Close

    wb1.Activate

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please indicate the lines where you get the error(s).

Comment: Your `tb1` declaration is incorrect - it should be: `Dim tb1 As ListObject`

Comment: `Range("D3").Select.Value.CompanyName` should probably be `Range("D3").Value = CompanyName`

Comment: Are you sure about your use of `[FILENAME]` or did you copy that from somewhere and are supposed to replace `[FILENAME]` by an actual filename?

Comment: `i` isn't declared. Thus -- you are not using `Option Explicit` in your modules. Bad idea. Most experienced VBA programmers enable the option `Require Variable Declaration` in the VBA editor options -- which automatically puts `Option Explicit` at the top of each module.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - I have moved it back into my personal macro book and it is highlighting the row starting "Set tb1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObject("Table1")"

Comment: @Rory- updated thank you

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - updated thank you & re [filename] that's just so I didn't include details of my company here

Comment: @JohnColeman - option explicit added- thank you, defined i as Dim i As Integer

Comment: Where are your errors now?

Comment: @Tom - thanks for your reply. I have updated the question above with the updated code and errors

Comment: one more tip: enable `ScreenUpdating` and go through the code line by line using F8

Comment: Use `wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")` (notice the `s`)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - updated as suggested. I am running through using F8  and get an issue now at the line `CompanyID = tb1.Range("A" & i)`
Error is "Runtime 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

Comment: try `tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells(i,1)`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct  - Really appreciating your help!! 

Adjusted and defined Company Name and ID as String and now no errors!!

Comment: If this macro is in your personal macro workbook, then wb1 would be PERSONAL.XLSB, wouldn't it? I'm also not sure about the circular logic of `set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` then using `wb1.Activate` shortly after.
I'm not sure how relevant this is.

Comment: @ChrisSlade `wb1.Activate` is actually relevant because `ThisWorkbook` does not have to be the active workbook but I think you're right that it shouldn't be `ThisWorkbook` in the first place, good catch!

Comment: `Dim i As Integer` is probably better replaced by `Dim i As Long`. The type `Integer` is somewhat pointless on 32 or 64 bit machines and isn't large enough to loop through all rows in larger ranges. Using that type in modern versions of Excel is an overflow error waiting to happen.

Comment: @ChrisSlade, 

Thank you so much! I have made updates and new code is above but still struggling

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - thank you as above, changes made in main body

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you as above, changes made in main body

Comment: @hann783 did you ever resolve this?  I'm getting the same exact system error code and am having a hard time tracking it down.

Comment: @Phillip no I didn't. All I ever did was change the error to somewhere else!